# Why does vapor pressure of ice decrease faster than water when temperature decreases?

Tags: aqueous-solution, phase

In melting point depression, I have learnt the explanation from the textbook that (e.g. aq. solution):

Definition of melting point: ice and water exist in equilibrium (have the same vapor pressure).

(1) aqueous solution generally has a lower vapor pressure than the pure solvent (water)

(2) Vapor pressure of ice drops faster than water when temperature drops

Therefore, at 0°C, the vapor pressure of water in aq. solution is lower than ice. When the temperature drops below 0°C, the drop in vapor pressure of ice can 'catch up' with water, hence an equilibrium can be reached i.e. melting point depression.

Question: I would like to know what is the rationale behind (2) since I have no idea on how to explain its validity.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not limited to ice+water, but is valid for solid+liquid phase of all compounds. The reason is that enthalpy of sublimation is higher than for evaporation, so the vapour pressure raises with temperature faster. See Clausius-Clapeyron equation. Related is slower decrease of vapour pressure with T for most organic solvents compared to water, as they have lower evap. enthalpy than water.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for letting me know the equation!